# Is there a way to completely hide the gutter of monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is it possible to completly hide the monaco-editor gutter.
I tried the following options:

```
  lineNumbers: 'off',
  glyphMargin: false,
  folding: false
```

This reduces the gutter size but it's still about 10 pixel wide and it grows back when hovering it.
Is there a way to suppress it completly?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two hidden options that allows to hide it completely

See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30795#issuecomment-410998882

```
{
  lineNumbers: 'off',
  glyphMargin: false,
  folding: false,
  // Undocumented see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30795#issuecomment-410998882
  lineDecorationsWidth: 0,
  lineNumbersMinChars: 0
}
```

Comment: I also needed to add showFoldingControls: "never",